# Pasa y obtener parametros de clase personalizada a Intent

Tags: android

Hola chicos esta vez quisiera preguntarles de qué forma paso y recibo parámetros de una clase personalizada que he creado a un intent

por ejemplo:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ValidarCumplimiento.class );

Vehiculo el_vehiculo = new Vehiculo("ASD384", true, 1, 45);
i.putExtra("vehiculo", el_vehiculo );
startActivity(i);
```

capturarlo (No se como hacerlo):

```
Bundle params = getIntent().getExtras();
hora = params.getString("vehiculo");
```

de ante mano muchas gracias por vuestra colaboración que es tan útil!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veo que estas colocando un objeto y luego estas intentando obtenerlo como string **params.getString("vehiculo");** lo cual es incorrecto.

Para poder hacer esto, puedo sugerirte implementar Serializable en la clase Vehiculo, la cual te permitirá pasar un objeto de una actividad a la otra.

Ejemplo

Para tu clase Vehiculo

```
public class Vehiculo implements Serializable {

}
```

Para colocar el valor en el Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ValidarCumplimiento.class );

Vehiculo el_vehiculo = new Vehiculo("ASD384", true, 1, 45);
i.putExtra("vehiculo", el_vehiculo );
startActivity(i);
```

Para obtener el objeto desde la actividad **ValidarCumplimiento**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras != null) {
  Vehiculo vehiculo = (Vehiculo) extras.getSerializable("vehiculo");
}
```

Comment: Perfecto de esta forma funcionó de maravilla, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Fue un placer haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas es enviar un objeto, en este caso `Vehiculo` para enviar un objeto, se realiza de esta forma, creas tu ArrayList de objetos y lo envias en el `Intent` mediante `.putExtra()`:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ValidarCumplimiento.class);
   intent.putExtra("vehiculo", vehiculo);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Para recibir el Objeto en la Activity se realiza de esta forma:

```
Vehiculo  vehiculo = (Vehiculo) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("vehiculo");
```

#### Es muy importante que para realizar esto tu objeto Vehiculo debe implementar la clase [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html):

```
public class Vehiculo implements Serializable {
```